# SAP BODS cannot fetch 255+ columns from Excel

Tags: excel, odbc, sap-data-services

We are facing an issue when uploading long texts (longer than 255 symbols) from Excel file using Data Services in SAP BODS.

Data Services ODBC driver truncates all further texts in this column to 255 symbols, even if the field length is defined as varchar(2500) in Excel file format in Data Services and if the column contains longer texts in next rows.

I tried to set parameter `TypeGuessRows = 0` but it's not working.

Also tried using keeping record on first row in source Excel but it's not working.

Does anyone know how to load max length data using SAP BODS?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue which is described in note [1675110](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/0001675110). This is default (faulty) behavior of SAP DS, which sets file width according **first 100 rows** of Excel book. The subsequent rows even longer ones will not be treated longer than 255 characters.

**SOLUTION:** move longer rows to the top 100 or make the fake first row of the necessary length which consider longest column in your book.